# httpclient jar conflicts.How to fix it?

Tags: java, ssl, jar, httpclient

//This is my code and i am working behind proxy ...

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultProxyRoutePlanner;

{
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxyhost", 8082); 
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);}
```

**//Following error appears on my console**

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContexts
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:966)
    at TwitterFeeds.main(TwitterFeeds.java:40)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

**I am using following jars**

```
httpclient-4.5.2.jar
httpcore-4.3.jar
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `SSLContexts` class has been relocated to another package in httpclient 4.4.

[Since 4.4](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContexts.html?is-external=true)

Upgrade your httpcore version to at least 4.4 to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the answer - [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ConnectionReuseStrategy:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746057/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-http-conne/36751707#36751707).

Update httpcore version to 4.4. It should work for you.