# Class not found exception for AppEngine with SendGrid

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sendgrid

I am using Google AppEngine with Java.
I am using SendGrid API to send emails.
So I downloaded the SendGrid library (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java).
I wrote a test application outside AppEngine with Java and it is sending emails properly.
When I tried to run the application with AppEngine, it is showing this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContexts
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:966)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
    at com.sendgrid.Client.<init>(Client.java:55)
    at com.sendgrid.SendGrid.<init>(SendGrid.java:29)
    at com.fms.advocacy.AdvocacyMail.send(AdvocacyMail.java:40)
    at com.fms.advocacy.AdvocacyMail.send(AdvocacyMail.java:36)
    at com.fms.advocacy.AdvocacyMail.send(AdvocacyMail.java:32)
    at com.fms.advocacy.api.auth.AuthenticationApi.forgotPassword(AuthenticationApi.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.AccessRuleFilter.doFilter(AccessRuleFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:32)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.ErrorHandlerFilter.doFilter(ErrorHandlerFilter.java:36)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:512)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Can anybody resolve the issue?

This is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.fms</groupId>
    <artifactId>advocacy</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <app.id>xyz-abc</app.id>
        <app.version>1</app.version>
        <appengine.version>1.9.42</appengine.version>
        <gcloud.plugin.version>2.0.9.74.v20150814</gcloud.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <version>${app.version}</version>
                    <address>0.0.0.0</address>
                    <port>8888</port>
                    <jvmFlags>
                        <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gcloud.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <set_default>true</set_default>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                                <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.mojo
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            versions-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>
                                                display-plugin-updates
                                            </goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please show how the `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContext` class is included on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendgrid depends on the Apache httpclient which is potentially problematic on GAE.

They have a special lib for GAE:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-google-java

See also:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sendgrid

So use `sendgrid-google-java` instead of `sendgrid-java`.

Comment: I tried that. but it is very basic. Also no documentation available for attachments and templates

Comment: It seems to be just a wrapper around Sendgrid's v2 web api: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/using_the_web_api.html so you could use the documentation there to see how to send attachments etc. It might actually be better to just use the v3 api right away and not use this sengrid-google-java lib itself. Just make sure to use java.net.HttpURLConnection or Google's own httpclient.

Comment: OK. I will try that. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss the `httpclient<version>.jar` in your classpath.

For gradle add the following dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'
```

Comment: Should this not be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @ppeterka No. It is the answer

Comment: Are you sure? The question is completely incomplete... Also, OP wrote `and it is sending emails properly` so on the his computer, stuff seems to work, so *that* classpath is OK. There is something wrong on the classpath on AppEngine - like the version conflict in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914117/httpclient-jar-conflicts-how-to-fix-it).

Comment: In my working program I only added the maven repository for app engine and Sendgrid Java client. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sendgrid/sendgrid-java/3.0.8 Also, when I add this repository will maven automatically download other required libraries automatically? isn't it the whole idea of maven?

Comment: @Harikrishnan Yes it is the idea of maven. But it can be that the developer not want to add some jars, because of different Versions and so on. So it is possible, that you have to add this manually

Comment: I added it now (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2), but still showing this error. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts

Comment: Show the changes you made and make sure that the file is part of your application

Comment: @Harikrishnan Looks ok. Can you verify if the jar contains the missing class?

Comment: No. that class is not there