# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE in bitpay SDK

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

I want to implement [this](https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/204593565#Java) code

```
public void testGetExchangeRate() throws Exception
{
    ECKey key = KeyUtils.createEcKey();

    String clientName = "server 1";
    BitPay bitpay = new BitPay(key, clientName);

    if (!bitpay.clientIsAuthorized(BitPay.FACADE_MERCHANT))
    {
        // Get Merchant facade authorization code
        String pairingCode = bitpay.requestClientAuthorization(
            BitPay.FACADE_MERCHANT);

        // Signal the device operator that this client needs to
        // be paired with a merchant account.
        System.out.print("Info: Pair this client with your merchant account using the pairing Code: " + pairingCode);
        throw new BitPayException("Error:client is not authorized for Merchant facade");
    }
}
```

I included these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.bitpay</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-bitpay-client</artifactId>
    <version>v2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

But when I run the code I get:

```
testGetExchangeRate(com.payment.gateway.bitpay.impl.BitpayImplTest)  Time elapsed: 1.665 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at com.payment.gateway.bitpay.impl.BitpayImplTest.testGetExchangeRate(BitpayImplTest.java:55)
```

**Question**: Can you give some advice how I can fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622885/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the maven dependencies of the `pom.xml` file of the library project on [github](https://github.com/bitpay/java-bitpay-client), although not the same artifact version, you can see that the `java-bitpay-client` depends on several libraries from `org.apache.httpcomponents`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Among which:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

In your dependencies you instead have `httpcore` version `4.4.5`, hence there is clearly a **dependency conflict**, as also pointed out by [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4564815/jacob) in the comments and the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622885/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance?rq=1) similar question.

Via [Maven dependency mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) mechanism, your build will pick up the latest, version `4.4.5`, because it is explicitely declared among your dependencies, hence at runtime `java-bitpay-client` will have in the classpath a different version of one of its dependencies, which may cause the final exception.

A possible solution would then be to remove the `httpcore` dependency from your `dependencies` and let it come into the classpath via transitive dependencies (version `4.3` should then get into).

You can also confirm the description above by running from the console on your project:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.github.bitpay
```

You should get, among other transitive dependencies, also `httpcore`.

---

Side note: I see you defined a dependency with `type` having value `jar`. You can omit that, `jar` is the default value for a dependency `type`, that is, dependencies are by default jar files. From official [pom reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies):

> **`type`**: Corresponds to the dependant artifact's `packaging` type. This defaults to `jar`.

Comment: I changed the version to 4.3. Now I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContext

Comment: @user1285928 you most probably missed an ending `s`, it's `SSLContexts` and [apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914117/httpclient-jar-conflicts-how-to-fix-it) it's again because of version issue, the class moved package from version `4.3` to `4.4`, hence something relies on the latter version while the client library is using the former.

Comment: Another approach would then be to change the version of the whole `httpcomponents` family by redeclare them in your `dependencies` section with the latest version, as such you would consistently use the new version across the family. That is, take the dependencies reported here above and change their version.

Comment: I tested it but I get again java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Comment: You mean by applying the second approach? OK, then we're sure it requires the previous version, which makes sense. We then need to fix the no class found exception.

Comment: @PeterPenzov can you please add to your question the output of the command `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.apache.httpcomponents` executed on your project?

Comment: apparently you also had a further dependency initially, `httpclient`, which you didn't mention. Hence, at the first attemp, when removing `httpcore` from your dependencies (which fixed the INSTANCE error), you still then had `httpclient` version `4.5.2` among your direct dependencies > which would cause the NoClassDefFound error, makes sense, incompatibility. However, when you explicitely declared all, you still got an error, hence some other dependencies is playing a role in this game. Can you run again `mvn dependency:tree` (without the `-Dincludes`) in both cases and post it?