# HttpClient java NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, json

I want to make a simple JSON client from java.
So I have build this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonSimple {
    private static final String FILENAME = "C:\\Users\\a41g.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonSimple s = new JsonSimple();
        s.http();
    }

    public HttpResponse http() {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;


        try {
            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

        }

        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String sCurrentLine;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

        }

        try {
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) { //THIS LINE GENERATED EXCEPTION
                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://mylik");

                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sCurrentLine);
                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                        request.setEntity(se);
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                        if (response != null) {
                            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;
    }
}
```

but if I try to start my application I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/Lookup
    at JsonSimple.http(JsonSimple.java:47)
    at JsonSimple.main(JsonSimple.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.Lookup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

I have insert a comment in my code near the line code that generate the exception.

> EDIT
>   this is the jar that I have imported in my project
>   [image]
>
> EDIT ( I have change .jar file) in this:

[image]

Comment: It seems that you didn't include all jar files

Comment: Add this library instead
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient43beta1jar.htm

Comment: may be your  answer having in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746057/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-http-conne

Comment: @BasilBattikhi what jar I should delete?

Comment: delete all apache jar files and replace them with that one

Comment: you should add httpcore-4.3.jar file and also check that you include  HttpCore file

Comment: I have insert and replace the jar file. But the error is the same

Answer (score 2):

`Lookup.class` is inside the `httpcore` jar file.
Make sure you have added `httpcore`.

It seems you have added just `httpclient` jar, but you'd need both `httpclient` and `httpcore` to run your code.

You can download it from the Maven repository:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore